# Mongoose/MongoDB removing items in model's array without stating which item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am encountering behavior with Mongoose/MongoDB I do not understand. Mongoose is removing users from an array even when there isn't a user specified.

Here's the schema:

```
var DocSchema = new Schema({
  doc_id  : String,
  users: [String],
});
```

And here is the controller to remove users from the array:

```
exports.remove_user = function(req, res) {
  doc_id = req.body.doc_id;
  username = req.body.username;
  Document.findOne({doc_id: doc_id}, function(err, doc_data) {
    if (err) {
      throw (err);
    } else {
      var users = doc_data.users;
      var index = users.indexOf(username);
      users.splice(index, 1);
      doc_data.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          throw (err);
        } else {
          console.log( 'removed user from doc' );
          return res.send( doc_data );
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

This PUT request works fine when I want to remove `tom` from the array (and only `tom`):

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/remove_user',
  type: 'PUT',
  data: {
      'doc_id': 66865270,
      'username': 'tom'
  },
  success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
      console.log( 'Post response:' );
      console.dir( data );
      console.log( textStatus );
      console.dir( jqXHR );
  }
});
```

However, let's say `tom` doesn't exist, or was already removed from the array, MongoDB will seemingly arbitrarily remove another user when I do same PUT request with `'username': 'tom'`.

How do I properly ensure only the explicitly stated username is removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `splice` incorrectly.

```
var users = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry'];
var index = users.indexOf('john');
users.splice(index, 1);
console.log(users);
//[ 'tom', 'dick' ]
```

It's not arbitrary, you are not checking whether `index >= 0`. You could avoid this entirely by just changing your criteria:

```
Document.findOne({doc_id: doc_id, users: username}, function(err, doc_data) {
```

That query will return a `null` doc_data if `doc.users` doesn't contain that username. Or you could just check `index` before calling `splice`.